# How and why does $\ln (e^{0.023t}) = 0.023t$

Tags: logarithms

How and why does $\ln (e^{0.023t}) = 0.023t$

I'm so confused.

Comment: By definition, $\ln$ and $\exp$ are inverses of each other (where they make sense). So I fail to see the confusion here.

Comment: How does one explain why one is confused? Somehow, I'd been working with ln and exp the last few months and must have passed over that rule, either going too quickly through material or just failing to make a note of it and forgot. Before I posted, I spent over an hour looking and researching. I guess I just didn't think it was easy and didn't look back far enough. What is easy/basic to one person isn't to another. Isn't what this forum is about? Tony & several others got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because $\ln e^x = x$ in general. The logarithm and exponential functions are inverses of each other.

Comment: Beat me to it by 3 seconds! +1

Comment: $f(x)=e^x \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x), e^{\ln x}\equiv Id$